# Outer gridview has extra column with nested gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code for the nested gridview within a gridview, but it is generating an extra blank column as shown in the following for the outer gridview header and row.  The code I use is the following.  Is there a way to to remove the extra blank column in the outer gridview.

Add the following code before the nested gridview:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit1" Text="<tr id='trGrid'><td colspan='4'>" />
```

Add the following code after the nested gridview:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit2" Text="</td></tr>" />
```

[image: Outer gridview with nested gridview below outer gridview row]

**UPDATE:**

If I change the colspan to 3, it looks like the following:

[image]

**UPDATE (ENTIRE GRIDVIEW CODE):**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdXML" runat="server" AllowSorting="false"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0"
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" onrowdeleting="GrdXML_RowDeleting" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound"
    ShowFooter="false" CssClass="xmlgrid" OnSorting="GrdXML_Sorting" DataKeyNames="ContractRecordID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contract Start Date" SortExpression="ContractStartDate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContractStartDate") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="30%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contract End Date" SortExpression="ContractEndDate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContractEndDate") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="50%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" 
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ContractRecordID") %>' CommandName="Delete" 
                    onclick="BtnDelete_Click" Text="Delete" Width="60px" />
                <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="BtnDelete_ConfirmButtonExtender" 
                    runat="server" ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to Delete?" Enabled="True" 
                    TargetControlID="BtnDelete">
                </ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="40px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit1" Text="<tr id='trGrid'><td colspan='3'>" />
                <asp:GridView ID="projectCodeGridView" runat="server" AllowSorting="false" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" OnRowCommand="ProjectCodeGridView_RowCommand" OnRowCreated="ProjectCodeGridView_RowCreated" OnRowDataBound="ProjectCodeGridView_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="ProjectCodeGridView_RowDeleting" DataKeyNames="ContractProjectCodeID" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Codes" SortExpression="ContractProjectCode" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContractProjectCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="100%" />
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="projectCodeTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="projectCodeRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="projectCodeTextBox" ErrorMessage="Project Code Required" ForeColor="Red" Display="Static"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <FooterStyle Width="100%" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="BtnDelete1" runat="server" 
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ContractProjectCodeID") %>' CommandName="Delete" 
                    onclick="BtnDelete1_Click" Text="Delete" Width="60px" />
                <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="BtnDelete1_ConfirmButtonExtender" 
                    runat="server" ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to Delete?" Enabled="True" 
                    TargetControlID="BtnDelete1">
                </ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="BtnAdd" runat="server" onclick="BtnAdd_Click" Text="Add" Width="60px" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <FooterStyle Width="100%" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" Font-Bold="True" />
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit2" Text="</td></tr>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="padding" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="padding" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: what if you change `colspan='4'` to `colspan='3'`?

Comment: The nested gridview row only spans the first 3 columns if i change the colspan to 3.

Comment: any other suggestions? (:

Comment: I think it does exactly what you wanted it to do because when you give `colspan='5'` for one of the rows (nested grid) it will obviously add as many columns for other rows of the table as well. You may have an option to remove the right border for the extra column using jquery or css and pretend as though it's a single column.

Comment: Can you pls post the entire gridview definition code from the .aspx?

Comment: This was answered her... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145867/gridvew-child-gridview-extra-column-wont-disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I tried your code locally. The reason you're getting the extra column is because that is the `<asp:TemplateField>` you are adding as the 4th column in the gridview for your nested gridview and you're wrapping it to the next line using a `<tr>`.

We can't remove that column, if you do so then you will not see the nested gridview. You can try `e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = false;` in the `OnRowDataBound` event which will remove the nested gridview.

**Here is what you can do to get around the issue.**

**1.** You don't actually need two `<asp:Literal..` controls in there and you can simply do something like below. Set `colspan="100%"`

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="100%">
                <asp:GridView ID="projectCodeGridView" ....// your child gridview
            </td>
          </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**2.** From your `GrdXML (parent gridview)` remove the property `GridLines="Both"` and set `GridLines="Horizontal"` in which way you can elimination the border for the columns.

**3.** If you need to show the right borders for gridheader and gridrow cells then using css specify the styles for `th` and `td` and link them to `<HeaderStyle CssClass = ..` and `<RowStyle CssClass = ..`. If you need to remove borders for certain column then use `:nth-child()` css property to tweak in.

Here is what I have got after applying some of the changes I suggested as above.

[image]